# How to align a column to the right in html

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I have created grid with a row including some input fields and now I need to create some buttons to the right of them, but I can't figure that out right.

This for responsive design and I can't find some resource that explain what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-md-3 col-lg-7">
            <h1>Select</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-input " placeholder="balal" id="input-type-text2"
                value="" name="input-type-text" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-input " placeholder="r" id="input-type-text4"
                value="" name="input-type-text" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-input " placeholder="lalala" id="input-type-text6"
                value="" name="input-type-text" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-24 col-sm-16 col-md-6 col-lg-14">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-input " placeholder="align to the right" id="input-type-text6"
                value="" name="input-type-text" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect the last col to align to the right

Comment: May be this would help https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap 4.0 or higher: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/

Comment: are u using grid 24 columns?

Comment: No, I need only 3 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CSS Grid` is perfect for responsive layouts.

You can declare the `.container` as `display: grid` and then you can define the columns and rows of your `.container` as:

- `grid-template-columns: 50% 50%`
- `grid-template-rows: 100%`

**Working Example:**

```css
.container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
grid-template-rows: 100%;
}

.right {
justify-self: end;
}

input[type=text] {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Select</h1>
<div class="container">
<div class="container-column left">
<input type="text" placeholder="balal" />
<input type="text" placeholder="r" />
<input type="text" placeholder="lalala" />
</div>

<div class="container-column right">
<input type="text" placeholder="align to the right" />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `class` name

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <h1>Select</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-input " placeholder="balal" id="input-type-text2"
        value="" name="input-type-text" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-input " placeholder="r" id="input-type-text4"
        value="" name="input-type-text" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-input " placeholder="lalala" id="input-type-text6"
        value="" name="input-type-text" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-input " placeholder="align to the right" id="input-type-text6"
        value="" name="input-type-text" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still get the last input filed aligned below the 3 above. It does not align to the right. @Lalji you wrote that I need to change the class name. Which class you mean?